# Emacs Orgmode: hiding other items in the tree

Tags: org-mode, focus

I have an org file, that looks like:

```
* Item 1
** Subitem 1.1
* Item 2
** Subitem 2.1
This text from Subitem 2.1 
** Subitem 2.2
```

I am editing text under Subitem 2.1. Is there a way to hide everything from the screen, except Subitem 2.1, so ideally while editing the text I just want to have a view like:

```
** Subitem 2.1
This text from Subitem 2.1
```

Answer (score 7):

What I need is:

```
C-x n s     (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    Narrow buffer to current subtree.
```

To widen the buffer again, use `C-x n w`

(from http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html)
P.S. I was googling using a wrong word: "hide" instead of "narrow" :)